# Problems with R mean function

Tags: r

I'm having problems with the mean function in R returning NA.

Here is my data (is.numeric returns TRUE):

```
[1] 0.0148 0.0033 0.0021 0.0018 0.0013     NA     NA     NA 0.0075 0.0068 0.0059 0.0037 0.0033 0.0025 0.0019 0.0018 0.0072 0.0064 0.0044
```

[20] 0.0027 0.0024 0.0024 0.0012 0.0004

Results of summary:

```
summary(Display_df$CTR)
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
0.000400 0.001900 0.002700 0.003991 0.005900 0.014800        3
```

Results of mean:

```
mean(Display_df$CTR, rm.na = T)
[1] NA
```

Any idea what is going wrong? I've never had this problem before, and it seems so simple.

Comment: Use `dput(df)` to provide sample data.

Comment: Did you mean `na.rm`?! I'm unaware of `rm.na`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistaking one argument. Here's how to reproduce the `NA`:

```
test<-c(1,2,3,NA,NA)
mean(test,rm.na=T)
```

This returns NA because R doesn't do calculations for NA. For instance `1+NA` will return `NA`. The correct arguments are shown below

```
mean(test,na.rm = T)
```

It's `na.rm` not `rm.na`.